# Should i call the parent class method with super() in the child class

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype, super

I have a question about super() in javascript.
Should i call the parent class method 'stringy()' with super() in the child class or i can use it like this:

```
function solve() {
class Melon {
    constructor(weight, melonSort) {
        if (new.target === Melon) {
            throw new Error('Abstract class cannot be instantiated directly.')
        }
        this.weight = weight;
        this.melonSort = melonSort;
        this._elementIndex = weight * Number(melonSort.length);

    }
    stringy() {
        return `Element: ${this.element}\nSort: ${this.melonSort}\nElement Index: ${this._elementIndex}`
    }
}

class Watermelon extends Melon {
    constructor(weight, melonSort) {
        super(weight, melonSort);
        this.element = 'Water';
    }
}
```

or

```
function solve() {
class Melon {
    constructor(weight, melonSort) {
        if (new.target === Melon) {
            throw new Error('Abstract class cannot be instantiated directly.')
        }
        this.weight = weight;
        this.melonSort = melonSort;
        this._elementIndex = weight * Number(melonSort.length);

    }
    stringy() {
        return `Element: ${this.element}\nSort: ${this.melonSort}\nElement Index: ${this._elementIndex}`
    }
}

class Watermelon extends Melon {
    constructor(weight, melonSort) {
        super(weight, melonSort);
        this.element = 'Water';
    }

    stringy(){
        return super.stringy();
    }
}
```

which one is correct and what is the difference.

Comment: You should not learn object oriented programming with JavaScript. Instead go for a language that properly supports this paradigm. Classes are just syntactic sugar in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to include `stringy` in `Watermelon` unless you want to change the behavior. `Watermelon` instances will inherit the `Melon` version if you don't. Your two versions of `Watermelon` are *very nearly* identical, and calls to `stringy` on instances of either version will create and return the same string. If `stringy` used arguments, your overwritten one would need to be sure to pass all arguments it received along, but `stringy` doesn't use any, so...

---

*(Just for completeness: The only* slight *difference is that in your second version of `Watermelon`, there is a `Watermelon.prototype.stringy` function, whereas in your first version there isn't. It's fine that there isn't, because `Watermelon.prototype` inherits from `Melon.prototype`, which has `stringy`.)*

Comment: …and the much more obvious difference is that the overriding method fails to pass arguments to the overwritten one.

Comment: @Bergi - The overwritten one doesn't use any arguments, so the point is moot.